# How to Set Up CORS enabled domain authentication cookie .Net Core?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, cookies, cors

I am trying to authenticate CORS origin requests and set Claims principle with the user of internal company single sign on utility. I have the current setting so far, the cookie will never get created on the domain set at the authentication setup.

I have an Angular client application and .Net Core 3.0 Webapi, the requirement is for the client to be able to set authentication for future api calls.

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>

{   
    options.Cookie.Name = "access_token";
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.Cookie.Domain = "localhost:xxxx";

});

//CORS
services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(
            "AllowOrigin",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("localhost:xxxx")
                .AllowCredentials()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod());
    });

//Sign In 
HttpContext.SignInAsync(
        scheme: CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        principal: new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)),
        properties: new AuthenticationProperties { ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.Add(120) });
```

I am testing this all on local so both URLS are localhost with different ports
Angular is hosted: `http://localhost:xxxx`
WebAPi is hosted :`http://localhost:xxx2`

http request from Angular to webapi is `http://localhost:xxx2/api/auth` which has the SignInAsync call, the company single sign does a username but the cookie never gets created. If I remove the `options.Cookie.Domain = "localhost:xxxx";` the cookie does get created on the webapi domain `http://localhost:xxx2`. I must be missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading up some other posts on stackoverflow , it tuned out that AllowAllOrigins will only fix this problem but poses a threat.

So I ended up fixing this issue with JWT - setting authorization token for every request sent from client interface. This issue was caused due to fact that the client and WebApi are hosted on different domains.